# Subtract seconds from a specific given time PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I writing a code for subtract seconds from a time using php. i have date which assigned to variable , i need to subtract seconds from that date.

```
$date="2014-03-16 17:40:27";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date) - strtotime("-600 seconds"));
```

but this gives me dates on 1970S, i search everhere and didn't found a answer which matched for my question. can anyone help me to fix this little code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`strtotime()` gives you a timestamp in seconds. Don't make another timestamp to subtract from it, just take 600 from it:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date) - 600);
//2014-03-16 17:30:27
```

Comment: @SunethKalhara Glad to have helped.